# unnecessary vertical scroll bar in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Can anyone help me remove unnecessary scroll bar in ie6.

Here is my url:

http://webberzsoft.com/clients/csslayouttest/template_new.php

Comment: Post your code man, not just a link!

Comment: @nickf: I could understand posting that to someone who's using IE6, but for someone who's developing with IE6 compatibility in mind it's just a pointless thing to say.

Comment: Well, it'll definitely remove the IE6 scrollbar :p. (yeah, it was a joke.)

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your CSS:

```
body{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

or inline, if you prefer:

```
<body style='overflow:auto;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want:

```
#wrapper{
    min-height:99%;
    width: 1240px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: hidden; /*HERE*/
}
```

In there too...